# pdf signature byte range is invalid

Tags: pdf, range, byte, digital-signature

When I try to verify the signature in Acrobat I get the following error message "there are errors in the formatting of information contained in this signature (The signature byte range is invalid)".
Here's the link to the signed file if anybody wants to have a look: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KTUfZwFeEjz5EKG61I7uuUzn6pyouEF7/view?usp=sharing.

Please help to verify the signature and share the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your file contains two concatenated copies of the same PDF. If you split it in half (after 441805 bytes), you get a single copy of the actual PDF. If you validate the signature in it, you'll not get the error message "there are errors in the formatting of information contained in this signature (The signature byte range is invalid)" anymore.

Adobe Acrobat complains because the byte range covers only half the file of a seemingly single-revision PDF while it only accepts signatures covering the full revision (except the placeholder for the embedded signature container) signed by the signature.